# Ubuntu server network driver installation

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, ubuntu-drivers, additional-drivers

A few days ago I reinstalled my server with Ubuntu server, and now face the problem that my network speed is about 5% of what it should be when using ethernet (wifi is disabled). I already had this problem a few months ago and eventually gave up and just used windows, but I really would like to stick to ubuntu now. I am guessing this is due to missing drivers, but honestly have no idea. I have attached the outputs of lspci and lshw -c network, so maybe someone here can guide me though what to do.
lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant (rev 01)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (rev 01)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01)
00:07.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Tigerlake Telemetry Aggregator Driver (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #2 (rev 20)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a0d3 (rev 20)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #4 (rev 20)
00:19.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #5 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b8 (rev 20)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tigerlake PCH-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev 20)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev 20)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 20)
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V (rev 20)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology P2 NVMe PCIe SSD (rev 01)
59:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz (rev 1a)
5a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-LM (rev 03)
```

lshw -c network:

```
  *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:59:00.0
   logical name: wlp89s0
   version: 1a
   serial: bc:09:1b:f4:15:b9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-72.uc latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:6a400000-6a403fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Controller I225-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:5a:00.0
   logical name: enp90s0
   version: 03
   serial: a8:a1:59:b0:7d:b2
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic duplex=full firmware=1053:8754 ip=192.168.178.222 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:19 memory:6a200000-6a2fffff memory:6a300000-6a303fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: eno1
   version: 20
   serial: a8:a1:59:b0:7d:b3
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:155 memory:6a600000-6a61ffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that both `enp90s0` and `eno1` support many link speeds, and have `autonegotiation` enabled.

You *could* be encountering an "autonegotiation storm", in which the hardware constantly re-negotiates the link speed, and you bandwidth goes away.

Pick a speed, and disable `autonegotiation`.

Read `man ip ip-link`, especially about:

```
[ rate TXRATE ]
[ max_tx_rate TXRATE ]
[ min_tx_rate TXRATE ]
[ state { auto | enable | disable }
```